# Listener not getting removed on component unmount in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have built a SPA in react.js, I am using react-router-dom, react-redux and some other modules.

I am using react-router-dom and I am using the switch component.

My routes:

```
const allRoutes = [
    {
      path: "/Intro",
      name: "Intro",
      component: Intro
    },
    {
      path: "/Room",
      name: "Room",
      component: Room
    },
    {
      path: "/Simulation",
      name: "Simulation",
      component: Simulation
    },
    {
      path: "/Cartypes",
      name: "Cartypes",
      component: CarTypes
    },
    {
      path: "/StartPosition",
      name: "StartPosition",
      component: StartPosition
    },
    {
      path: "/Movment",
      name: "Movment",
      component: Movment
    },
    { redirect: true, path: "/", to: "/Intro", name: "Intro" }
  ];

  export default allRoutes;
```

How I render them.

```
          <Switch>
              {routes.map((prop, key) => {
                if (prop.redirect)
                    return <Redirect from={prop.path} to={prop.to} key={key} />;
                return (
                  <Route path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />
                );

              })}
          </Switch>
```

**Scenario**:

In one of my components I wanted to detect when the user left that specifc component, when the url changed.

For this I found that I could with the help of `withRouter` get access to a listner that detects url changes. I put this in componentWillMount:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
      console.log("on route change");
      console.log(location)
      console.log(action)
    });
  }
```

Once the user changes url this fires which is desiered...but. 
Lets say that I am at "/simulation" and this is where I listen for any url change. when I move to "/room" the code that is in  componentWillMount in the "/simulation" component executed and now I am on a new url...

**Problem**: If I would now change from "/room" to "/intro" then the same code that is in componentWillMount under "/simulation" would execute again.

Can anyone tell me why? and how to stopp it from executing several times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would happen because once the component unmounts you are not clearing the history listener, you need to clear the listener when the component unmounts which you will do in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecyle method of `Simulation` like

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unlisten();
}
```

Comment: This is so simple and so logical, I can't believe that I did not think of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct...however I found an issue with unregistering inside of

```
componentWillUnmount
```

The problem was that the code that I had in `componentWillMount`never got the chance to execute since the `componentWillUnmount` got executed first/faster.

So I ended up with the following:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
      // execute my code
      this.unlisten(); // unregister the listner. 
    });
  }
```